# How to build a bitcoin fullnode and light node using docker image?

Tags: bitcoind, full-node

I used the image "fullnode/bitcoin" to build a node of bitcoin.
It runs successfully and I can see the debug.log. The node begin to Sync ledger(blocks).

I want to know how I can judge one node is fullnode or light node. The difference in bitcoin.conf? Or the difference in log?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin Core only implements a fully-validating node mode. If this image runs Bitcoin Core, it's fully validating.

It *is* possible to run Bitcoin Core in pruning mode (`prune` setting in bitcoin.conf), where old block data is deleted *after* validation. Everything is still downloaded and validated as before, just not kept.